# Deadlock executing Query in Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, deadlock

I've the following Linq:

```cs
var qry = s.GetTable<MessageEventDTO>().Where(x => x.MessageName == messageName && x.SourceTyp == sourceTyp && x.Source == source && (x.Status == MessageEventStatus.open || x.Status == MessageEventStatus.acknowledged));

goneMessages = qry.ToList();

var ret = qry
    .Set(x => x.Status, x => x.Status | MessageEventStatus.gone)
    .Set(x => x.TimestampGone, timeStamp)
    .Update();
return ret;
```

which will be converted to following SQL:

```sql
UPDATE MessageEvents SET Status = Status | 1, TimeStampGone = @1
WHERE MessageName = @2 AND SourceTyp = @3 Source = @4 AND (Status = 0 OR Status = 2)
```

the problem is now, there are multiple Updates run in parallel, and I got deadlock exceptions, but I do not understand why?

see also
[image]

[image]

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table? Deadlocks are often avoided with index tuning.

Comment: Are you opening transactions in your code? I think that shouldn't happened when you don't use transactions...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want another process to be able to start the select portion of the update, use the `UPDLOCK` hint or set an appropriate transaction isolation level (`REPEATABLE READ`).

See [John Huang's Blog](http://www.sqlnotes.info/2012/10/10/update-with-updlock/) for a more thorough explanation of how nonclustered indexes can cause deadlocks.

Example using Linq to SQL which is not prey to this issue:

```
var opts = new TransactionOptions();
opts.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead;
using (var txn = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, opts))
{
    // update command goes here.

    txn.Complete();
}
```